# Enhancing my WCF service with asynchronous calls?

Tags: winforms, wcf

I am currently developing a WCF service in a windows form application. There would be a simple GUI screen with 2 buttons, "Start" and "Stop". Whenever I attempt to start the service, the UI of the application would temporary hangs until it loads finish. Is it possible to add a loading effect to it? And how can I do that.

Still pretty new in this area. Would welcome any comments!

Is there any good tutorials out there that teaches how can I enhance this issue?

I have read the MSDN blog tutorial from Rick Rainey *[Making asynchronous service calls from a WinForm client](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/03/18/making-asynchronous-service-calls-from-a-winform-client.aspx)* but it is not really that of a good tutorial.

Just to clarify, my WCF service is a publish subscribe framework and I think I do not need to be able to call the operations asynchronously. All I want to know is how do I initiate the connection asynchronously.

Comment: Could you clarify more on that "initiate the connection asynchronously"?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add a loading effect to it? And how can I do that.

For this you can [use duplex service contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx).

Also, since your application is a subscription application you might want to look into pushing data to your application from the WCF service. Here's a nice example and although it's for Silverlight I think it might be useful to you:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx